# Is it possible to change the lookup dns location of dns_get_record

Tags: php

Say for example I want to use

```
dns_get_record("domain", DNS_ALL);
```

Is it possible to use that to use an external dns lookup, I'm looking for something like this:

```
dns_get_record("sitetolookup.com","sitetouseforlookup.com", DNS_ALL);
```

Is there anything in PHP that allows that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a PEAR package that will do it.

http://netdns2.com/

```
//
// create new resolver object, passing in an array of name
// servers to use for lookups
//
$r = new Net_DNS2_Resolver(array('nameservers' => array('192.168.0.1')));

//
// execute the query request for the google.com MX servers
//
try {
        $result = $r->query('google.com', 'MX');

} catch(Net_DNS2_Exception $e) {

        echo "::query() failed: ", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```